# Custom-validated form won't submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I wrote a script which allows me to validate a form with my Zend_Form validators instead of a classic client-side validation (like jQuery Validate) + server-side validation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var form = $('form'); // target form
var requests = [], validations = [];
var nbInputs = $('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]').length; // number of inputs (text/password) in the form
var cancelSubmit = true;

form.submit(function() {

    // if we call the submit inside the function, skip validation
    if(cancelSubmit === false) {
        console.log('[-] cancelSubmit is false. Validation skipped.');
        return true;
    }

    console.log('[-] Entering validation');

    // resetting requests and validations results
    requests.length = 0;
    validations.length = 0;

    // for each input (text/password), get the validation status from the server
    $('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]').each(function(i) {

        var validatorField = $(this).attr('data-validator');
        var valueField = $(this).val();

        postData = {
            validator: validatorField,
            value: valueField
        };

        // storing requests into an array
        requests.push($.post('/validate', postData));
    });

    (function($) {
        $.whenAll = function() {
            return $.when.apply($, arguments);
        };
    })(jQuery);

    // when all the requests are done and returned a response
    $.whenAll(requests).then(function() {
        // show the validation status for each input
        $.each(requests, function(i, element) {
            element.done(function(data) {

                json = $.parseJSON(data);
                formGroup = $('input:eq('+i+')').parent();

                // if it isn't valid, show error
                if(json.valid == 0) {
                    if($('span.help-block', formGroup).length == 0) {
                        $(formGroup).addClass('has-error').append('<span class="help-block">'+json.message+'</span>');
                        $('label', formGroup).addClass('control-label');
                    }
                    // and store the validation status
                    validations.push(0);
                }
                // else, remove error
                else if(json.valid == 1) {
                    $(formGroup).removeClass('has-error');
                    $('.help-block', formGroup).remove();
                    // and store the validation status
                    validations.push(1);
                }

                // if we got all the validations required
                if(validations.length == nbInputs)
                {
                    console.log('[-] All validations have been done.');
                    if($.inArray(0, validations) == -1){
                        console.log('[-] No errors. Submitting form.');
                        cancelSubmit = false;
                        form.submit();
                    }
                    else
                        console.log('[-] There are still errors.');
                }
            });
        });
    });

    return false;
});
});
```

The validation page server-side send a JSON : `{ valid: 0, message: "error message" }` or `{ valid: 1}`.

I can't have the form to be submitted. When I enter valid values, it does skip validation, but don't submit the form. I have to hit the submit button again to make it work (but, I could have entered non-valid values that wouldn't be checked in this time, as `cancelSubmit`is set to `false`).

Isn't `return true;` supposed to submit the form when used inside a `.submit()` ?

Comment: Can you include the HTML markup? How about instead of calling "form.submit();" again you execute "return true"

Comment: @wavedrop I made a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/5qy6r/) but didn't post it when I realized this was server-side validation so it wouldn't work :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  It's looks like client side code to me. I understand that you are validating on the server by executing $.post.  Seems to me that you just need to return true when you want to submit the form.  The program is already within the submit function when it executes form.submit() again so rather than call form.sumbit() just return true.

Comment: Even if I replace the `form.submit()` with `return true;`, it does enter the `[-] No errors. Submitting form.` part but doesn't submit it. I have to re-submit it by clicking the submit button.

Comment: @wavedrop the `whenAll()` request is asynchronous, and the `.submit()` returns `false` by default. That why I think I have to trigger `.submit()` again, telling it to return `true` if all the validations have been passed.